# Is there a shorter way than a match or if let to get data through many nested levels without increasing the total amount of code?

Tags: rust

I work with a bunch of structs / enums included in each other. I need to get `ty.node<TyKind::Path>.1.segments.last().identifiers` and `ty.node<TyKind::Path>.1.segments.last().parameters<AngleBracketed::AngleBracketed>.types`.

Is there a simpler way to get these two values then my implementation of `f`? My ideal syntax would be:

```
ty.node<TyKind::Path>?.1.segments.last().identifiers
// and 
ty.node<TyKind::Path>?.1.segments.last().parameters<AngleBracketed::AngleBracketed>?.types
```

It that's impossible, maybe there is a way to reduce the number of `if let`? I want to solve only this particular case, so simplification should be possible compared to `f`. If an analog of `Option::map` / `Option::unwrap_or_else` were introduced, then the sum of its code + the code in `f` should be less then my original `f`.

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Ty {
    node: TyKind,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
enum TyKind {
    Path(Option<i32>, Path),
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Path {
    segments: Vec<PathSegment>,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct PathSegment {
    identifier: String,
    parameters: Option<Box<PathParameters>>,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
enum PathParameters {
    AngleBracketed(AngleBracketedParameterData),
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct AngleBracketedParameterData {
    types: Vec<Box<Ty>>,
}

/// If Tylnode == Path ->  return last path segment + types
fn f(ty: &Ty) -> Option<(String, Vec<Box<Ty>>)> {
    match ty.node {
        TyKind::Path(_, ref path) => if let Some(seg) = path.segments.iter().last() {
            let ident = seg.identifier.clone();
            println!("next_ty: seg.id {:?}", seg.identifier);
            match seg.parameters.as_ref() {
                Some(params) => match **params {
                    PathParameters::AngleBracketed(ref params) => {
                        Some((ident, params.types.clone()))
                    }
                    _ => Some((ident, vec![])),
                },
                None => Some((ident, vec![])),
            }
        } else {
            None
        },
        _ => None,
    }
}
```

To simplify the question, I have removed unrelated enum variants and struct fields.

Comment: @Shepmaster I update my question, I do not like gap between what I want `ty.node<TyKind::Path>.1.segments.last().identifiers` and how much code I need to write to get what I want.

Comment: *without introducing analogs of Option::map/unwrap_else* — why? Those functions exist *because* they provide value.

Comment: In a similar vein, what other restrictions are you imposing on any potential answers? Are answerers prohibited from creating *any* new functions?

Comment: *between what I want* — but what you want *underspecifies* what to do in the error cases. How would such a syntax know what should be done when (1) the enum **isn't** one of those types (2) when there are no segments so `last` returns `None` (3) the fact that you want to return `None` in some cases and a default value in others?

Comment: For example, I'd probably write something [like this](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=f27912ede77033ec2fe2b8ec2a813973&version=stable), but I can't tell if that meets whatever arbitrary restrictions have yet to be said.

Comment: @Shepmaster I update my question. I want to solve only one particular case. `Option::map` is convenient because of `Option::map` + many places where possible to use `Option::map` instead of `if let Some(x)` good in compare with many `if let Some(`, but if you use `if let Some(x)` only once then better write just `if let Some(`

Comment: @user1244932, you probably should propose RFC for expanding Rust in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The closest you can get, using nightly features and helper code, is probably this

```
fn f(ty: &Ty) -> MyOption<(String, Vec<Box<Ty>>)> {
    let last = ty.node.path()?.segments.my_last()?;
    Just((
        last.identifier.clone(),
        last.ab_parameters()
            .map(|v| v.types.clone())
            .unwrap_or_else(|| vec![]),
    ))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=bc6b2b5fbb78bc5d0192b7eac1968efe&version=nightly)

Comment: Thanks, why `MyOption`, no `TryTrait` for `std Option`?

Comment: @user1244932, orphan rules. You can't implement trait from another crate for type from another crate.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is called Lenses. Not sure about Rust, but here is about Haskell https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Lenses_and_functional_references

It might be possible to implement that in Rust, if somebody haven't done yet.

Comment: Lenses are used in Haskell to be able modify a part of a structure. In Rust you can just use (possibly mutable) references to focus on a part of a structure. I'm not sure how you think references would work in Rust or how they would help OP. In any case, this would be better as a comment since you didn't provide a solution.